# not able to install gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I was trying to install this gem https://github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging into a rails application.

The README gave instructions to put this in my Gemfile

```
gem 'messaging', git: 'git://github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging.git'
gem 'mailboxer', git: 'git://github.com/dickeytk/mailboxer.git'
```

However, when I tried to run bundle install, i got this error message

```
Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/dickeytk/mailboxer.git' "/Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-rc1@rails321/cache/bundler/git/mailboxer-d05808c480dfc6c9f04b8334dfdf7879cea63172" --bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /Users/mm/Sites/shawsome has failed.
```

I googled the error message and saw that some people had gotten this error message when they didn't have git installed. However, I've been using git for a while without problem. Anyone have any suggestions as to what might be the problem.

I also tried changing the syntax to no avail

gem 'messaging', :git => 'git://github.com/frodefi/rails-messaging.git'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a github account at https://github.com/dickeytk so that's probably why the git command is failing. Consider just using mailboxer from rubygems:

```
gem 'mailboxer'
```

or the repo that's linked to as the homepage from rubygems.org for this gem:

```
gem 'mailboxer', git: 'git://github.com/ging/mailboxer.git'
```